# Writing the value of certain keys of a json file to a postgresql table with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy, insert

How do I write the values of certain keys contained in the result.json file to the table I created. the values in the certain keys will be written in the columns I have created.  I have id, title, score columns in my table. I want to write the value opposite the title key in the title column and the value opposite the score key in the score column.

**result.son file:**

```
[
  {
    "title": "Street Basketball Association",
    "appId": "com.sba.android.googleplay",
    "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sba.android.googleplay",
    "icon": "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/a17t8kK_A4TMJtV0l6oTGzOvLbu_QlnKiWZM3L4RB-xprNL57z1YAJlal9ewEPrWxrW3=w240-h480-rw",
    "developer": "ShakaChen",
    "currency": "USD",
    "price": 0,
    "free": true,
    "summary": "We will bring you the hottest basketball game experience.You can invite other players to a real-time online competition or rank up while playing various league, cups and events in spectacular arenas.",
    "scoreText": "4.0",
    "score": 4.315321
  }
]
```

the name of my database is `test` :in this database, I have a table with one `test_table`.

**My code:**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgres://username:password@localhost:5432/test'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Test(test.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'test_table'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    score = db.Column(db.Float)

with open('./result.json') as my_file:
    dicts = load(my_file)

for dictionary in dicts:
    test_data = Test(app_name=dictionary['title'],
                                    developer=dictionary['developer'],
                                    score=dictionary['score'])

    db.session.add(test_data)
    db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your `Person` model has `score` field set to `db.Integer`, yet in the data you're getting, `score` is set to `float`. This will cause a `Data MisMatch` error.

Now, for the `json` part.

You import the `load` method from the `json` module so you're able to convert `json` objects to `Python dicts`.

```py
from json import load
```

You open your file, preferably inside a `context` so the file gets automatically released once you're done with it.

```py
with open('result.json') as my_file:
    dicts = load(my_file)
```

Now `dicts` is a list of `dict` objects on which you can operate.
You initiate a new instance of your `Person db.model` and assign each of the values to the appropriate field.

```py
for dictionary in dicts: #Remember, you have a list of dicts.
    person = Person(app_id=dictionary['appId'], 
                  title=dictionary['title'], score=dictionary['score']) 
                  #Remember to set the score field to the appropriate datatype. 
                  #i.e: db.Float
    db.session.add(person) #Add your new person instance to the session.
    db.session.commit() #Persists the user to your database.
```

**Update**:
Based from what I understood from your comment. You can set your `db.Model` as follows :

```py
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'test'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    app_id = db.Column(db.String(10), index=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    score = db.Column(db.Float) #You're getting float values.
```

Now, you have the `id` set by your database and the `app_id` from the `json` file. And you always have the option to search by the former or the latter.

Comment: There is a problem, the id will not be read from the json file, it will be self-increasing and unique.

Comment: Let me update my solution real quick.

Comment: @ahjfoışsjhofeşsfn You can set the `apple.id` field's length to whatever number suits your need best. If you have other questions, feel free to ask them.

Comment: I have many an error:  `(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'builtin_function_or_method'`

Comment: Please update your question with the full traceback. (All the lines of the error). Or you can paste it to a pastebin and get rid of it later. That error can come from typo, among many other reasons.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer. You have to set the `score` column to `Float` not `Integer`. If you still get an error, please copy the full error. Starting from `Traceback most recent call last`.

Comment: `psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation: null value in column "id" of relation "test_table" violates not-null constraint`

Comment: Answer updated : By setting `autoincrement` to `True` in the `db.Model`, Sqlachemy will increment the id automatically. Also, please assure me that you've set your `score` column to be of type `db.Float`

Comment: It's still same. I added `errors screenshots`. Can you check please?

Comment: In the first line of your screenshot, there's a line saying : There's another error above. Can you please paste that error as well ? Also, did you set the `autoincrement=True` to your `id` column ?

Comment: Please read carefully my answer and follow it thouroughly. No error appears on my end. Especially the `Person` class model.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've kept you busy. i just forgot to do automatic ascending in the table. I'm sorry.

Comment: That's what `autoincrement=True` is for. No need to be sorry, I've been in your position before. Please accept my answer, if you found it helpful and have great day. ( :